# Rails #raw or #html_safe methods are truncating text. Is there anyway around this?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and am trying to put together a little app that will read cucumber results from a mongo database.  The results stored in the document are parsed into html. In the rails app I am taking those results and displaying them using the raw() method call.  The string that I get back is fairly large and as it turns out, the raw() method is truncating the text that I pass into it. When I output the text without raw() I get the entire string as expected (except that it has been escaped and not rendering as html).

My question is, is there any way to get around this?  I really don't want to have to do the html conversion in the rails app or on the client. Both seem too costly.  Especially when I can do it elsewhere and just store it in monogdb as an html string.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Could you show your string?

Comment: It is far too long to put in the comments, but it is a lot of this "<div class='feature'><p>Using the default profile...# 2499: Support finding your own postings<br/><span class='skip'>@refactor</span> <span class='skip'>@TSP-2499</span><br/>Feature: Post Management, Unpost<br/>  <br/>  As a user who has made a posting<br/>  I want to unpost (cancel, manually expire, \"put on hold\") my posting<br/>  So that it is no longer publicly visible, though I might want to repost it after a while.<br/><br/>  # CSB calls this Cancellation<br/>  <span class='skip'>@smoke</span>"

Comment: I don't think length is an issue here. Converting a string with 1M characters works fine: `("a" * 1000000).html_safe.length #=> 1000000`

Comment: hmm, interesting. I have been looking through the implementation of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer and am having trouble wrapping my head around how exactly they did this. From what I can tell, they override a lot of the string methods injecting the html_safe? check to a lot of the functions.  If that flag isn't true, they send it off to the ERB::Utils to get converted.  Is it possible that a piece of incorrectly written html would stop the raw method in its tracks?  I'll have to keep looking. I can't help but feel I am missing something simple and that this is a dumb problem to have. :-/

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a part of the string that was causing the rendering of the html to choke. Because cucumber syntax pass variables to Scenario steps using < >, there were places that `<style>` was written.  Because  is a valid open html tag, the html stopped rendering.  I found this out by looking at the page source (where I was using the inspect element on the developer tools before).  I saw that the whole html that I was expecting was in the source.  I parsed through the text and used gsub to replace the `<style>` tag and all is working now.